# HTML Paste-Event, limit paste area to div border

Tags: html, jquery, paste, jquery-events

I use paste event at **html-div-element** for letting the user to paste an image.

I want the user to stand on the div when he pastes the image.

So I bind the paste event to the `div` selector.

The problem is that the event is fired each time when user press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, even when the mouse doesn't stand on the div.

I tried to check on the `event.currentTarget` - may be I can ask if it is the `div`, but it always give me the `div` selector, even when the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> happens when I am on other element.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="myPasteZone" style="border:1px solid black;height: 150px;width: 35vw"></div>
```

Javascript (type-script):

```
 $('#myPasteZone').bind("paste", (e)=>{
        const file = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.files[0];
        if(file){                
            this.addNewAttachment(file); 
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to limit the paste event only on the `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I added `tabIndex` to the div so it can be focused. Then when it is only focused only then will you be able to paste.
Demo: (ctrl + v)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myPasteZone').bind("paste", (e) => {

    try {
      if ($(":focus")[0].id === "myPasteZone") { // check if div focused
        const file = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.files[0];
        if (file) {
          this.addNewAttachment(file);
        }
        console.log('pasted');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    } // catch if id not exist
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="myPasteZone" tabindex="-1" style="border:1px solid black;height: 150px;width: 35vw"></div>

  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <p>hello, world</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why but the 'focus' selector not succeed to catch the div, even when I force div to be focused by debug tool.
I try to use hover selector but in this case I need to loop on the hovered array.
Not very good, but work.

Comment: the demo is not working for you?? which browser and what version are you using?

Comment: the demo work ok, but at my project - $(':focus') return me empty array. (i have version 1.6.2)

Comment: user  emineminems  I'm sorry I tried to edit the jquery version of your answer for try check it and I not succeed to cancel editing please change it yourself.

Comment: @user5260143 I edited my answer to use jQuery version 1.6.2. It is working fine. hope it helps

Comment: @user5260143 also, don't for get to use `tabIndex`attribute on the div so you can enable it to be focused. if you do not want to change the html, you can do this via jquery `.attr()`

Comment: I do it but not help. may be other library I use has a side-effect that disrupt it.